# Unable to invoke checkPointInCircle method in this test program I did

Tags: java, methods

I'm writing a test program currently to check for points within a circle. But the method to check if the point is in the circle isn't invoked. Did I do something? Can someone kindly advise on how to solve this issue?

```
 btSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            rad = spRadius.getSelectedItem().toString();
            if (rad.equals("1km")) {
                circle.setRadius(500);
                processJSON();

            } else if (rad.equals("100m")) {
                circle.setRadius(50);
                processJSON();

            } else if (rad.equals("500m")) {
                circle.setRadius(250);
                processJSON();
            }
        }

 private void processJSON() {
    try {
        if (mJSONObject != null) {
            Iterator<String> keys = mJSONObject.keys();
            while (keys.hasNext()) {
                String key = keys.next();
                JSONObject jsonObj = mJSONObject.getJSONObject(key);
                String point = jsonObj.getString("coords");
                String[] latlong = point.split(",");
                latpoint = Double.parseDouble(latlong[0]);
                lngpoint = Double.parseDouble(latlong[1]);
                Toast.makeText(this,latpoint+"+"+lngpoint,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (checkPointInCircle(latcenter, lngcenter, latpoint, lngpoint)) {
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().
                            position(new LatLng(latpoint, lngpoint)).title("busstop"));
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public boolean checkPointInCircle(double latcenter, double lngcenter, double latpoint, double lngpoint) {



    Double radi = Double.parseDouble(rad);
    double latdiff = (latpoint - latcenter);
    latdiff = Math.pow(latdiff, 2);
    double longdiff = (lngpoint - lngcenter);
    longdiff = Math.pow(longdiff, 2);
    radi = Math.pow(radi, 2);

    if (latdiff + longdiff < radi) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Tried putting some logging in? One of the conditions on the way to checking is probably failing.

Comment: @EvanKnowles sorry but logging? do you mind explaining?

Comment: Using a logging framework, or just good old `System.out.println`, and print what's happening at each point. Or just step through with a debugger.